# How to solve: "This app can't run on your PC To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher" (Windows11) trying to run 32 bit app?

Tags: windows-11, compatibility, 32-bit, assembly, system32

For doing crucial chapters in Peter's and Hyde's assembly manuals, there is the need to run this SIMX86.EXE [32 bit app. Built-in assembler (compiler), debugger, and interrupter for the x86 (hypothetical CPU)](https://github.com/veleita/86SIM-Assembly-exercises & also in Hyde's website [aoa.zip]).

I have a Windows 11 running on a VirtualBox over a MacBookPro.

When I double-click on the program, a solid blue window shows with this message: "This app can't run on your PC To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher".

Things I tried (everything i found on youtube & webs):

- Copied the `switch.vbx bivbx11.dll` files mentioned in the `README` to: `System`, `System32`, `SysWOW64` folders (CH03 folder).
- Running everything with admin permissions (my local/usual account is already admin).
- Auto compatibility wizard/manual options (right-click settings).
- Event Viewer for trying to "disable entry" in the Compatibility 32 bit database. (weird that even the tries to execute didn't get recorded in the Event Viewer).
- Deactivating SmartScreen protection.
- Deactivating Developers Protections.
- sfc /scannow (?¿).
- Activating the IIS Manager and combo "true" the allowance for 32 bit apps.
- ...

Everything I found. Nothing worked.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147635/discussion-on-question-by-nostromo-how-to-solve-this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 32-bit Windows 8.1, which runs well in [VirtualBox](https://oracle-virtualbox.net/pc/29-virtualbox-for-windows-81.html). Coincidentally, I recently needed to run a 32-bit Windows application. After trying Hasleo's excellent [Win2USB](https://www.hasleo.com/) and similar tools, I found they were too slow for my purpose. It took far less time to install VBox, and create a Win 8.1 machine, than did the alternatives.

Comment: Can you put some light on this ongoing debate about the Windows 8.1 thing (not available for purchase but also not clear the using it in like a demo fashion/castrated way [and castrated in what sense? Annoying activation messages? Shortcuts & tricks that are not really allowed?]?). Can you explain why even being a 32 bit application that should run in a x86_64 arch, it doesn't? Is there any other more less weighty solution than installing this other os? Just tweaking something in my W11 would be awesome. Thx.

Comment: VirtualBox community might be the place to ask your questions. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Community. A *loooong* chain of comments does not help a user get an answer, and there might be better answers at VB.

Comment: Why Virtual Box? This seems having nothing to do with it. Were you aware of this issue? Seems to be a classic Win 10/11 issue. Message/box/banner that shows up is extremely fast, W. native, nothing like something beyond Windows frontiers (i.e. VB dialogs). Is a very known issue present in many places most of them far from VB context (i.e. native installations). I. e. my Win 11 is a purchased native .ISO true and complete, nothing "specially tailored" for VB. Have to deeply disagree with your last suggestion. Have agreed if you have pointed a precise part of the VB forum this was debated.

Comment: This is the banner/message/error that appears: https://imgur.com/a/2FhPaEq
(very known: is called, the "This app can't run on your PC To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher" issue).